# Difference between Sales order and database

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, reports

In Magento 1.9 when generating a Sales order report (Report -> Sales -> Orders) for February I expect the same value total in invoiced column compared to running below:

`select sum(base_total_invoiced), day(created_at) as dag from sales_flat_order where state ='complete' and created_at between '2019-02-01 00:00:00' and '2019-03-01 00:00:00' group by dag;`

However none of the days do match, which feel strange as I believe they are in the same timezone.

Comment: The timezone in the database is UTC, so if you do not use UTC in your store you need to consider that offset in your statement (the report SQL does that), otherwise you may have some shift around midnight. Additionally not only orders with state = 'complete' may be included in the report.

Comment: Ok, this might be the case then. Store is running in CET. On the other hand if we change to UTC settlements of card transfers are still sent in CET.